# Adding a class to a helper method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a helper method that I am trying to apply css to without putting it in a div or any other element. How would I go about applying the css class to this helper in rails?

I tried:

```
<%= first_letter_content(e.content), :class => "first-letter" %>
```

and

```
<%= (first_letter_content(e.content), :class => "first-letter") %>
```

both resulting in `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'`

Helper code:

```
def first_letter_content(content) 
  first_letter = content[0] 
  return first_letter 
end
```

Any suggestions? I have been trying to find the proper syntax, but no luck.

Comment: How does your implementation look like?

Comment: Show us `first_letter_content` code.

Comment: `code
def first_letter_content(content)
  first_letter = content[0]
  return first_letter
 end`

I can't figure out how to display in code :\

Comment: @Matthew I edited your question and added the helper code inside the question itself (more readable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper does not support options (extra args) but you are trying to give a HTML class to the element.

You should wrap the content of `first_letter_content` inside a div/span (depending on what you want, block or inline) and apply the class on this HTML element:

```
<div class='first-letter'>
  <%= first_letter_content(e.content) %>
</div>
```

---

Or you can directly wrap the `content[0]` inside a `div` in the helper method:

```
def first_letter_content(content, options = {}) 
  content_tag(:div, content[0], options)
end
```

And use it like this:

```
first_letter_content(content, class: 'first-letter')
first_letter_content(content, class: 'first-letter', id: 'something')
first_letter_content(content)
```

---

Also, you can refactor your helper method to this:

```
def first_letter_content(content) 
  content[0]
end
```

It is a minor improvement but in Ruby the "last thing" used in a method will be returned by this method.

Examples:

```
def something
  a = 2
  b = 3
  a
end
# => returns `2`

def something_else
  a = 2
  b = 3
end
# => returns `3`

def whatever
  a = 12
  nil
end
# => returns `nil`
```

Comment: Thank you. Just curious, is there any way to have an arg of css class type?


I forgot all about having my css class have the inline property, that solves the issue about new lines.

Comment: @Matthew: there's no such type :)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to apply css to without putting it in a div or any other element

Css classes are for DOM elements, so you should wrap this content into some element/node.

For example:

```
def first_letter_content(content, css_class) 
  content_tag(:div, content[0], class: css_class)
end
```

Call:

```
<%= first_letter_content(e.content, "first-letter") %>
```